# Jfrog Xray function- numpy licensing check

Tags: numpy, pip, artifactory

I recently did a Xray scan of my pip remote repository (managed on Jfrog) and I noticed that numpy is listed to have multiple different licenses. Can somebody provide a bit of insight on this topic as I always believed that numpy is a bsd based license, but I keep seeing multiple different licenses (such as GPL3). Do I need to be wary of this if I ever decide to do something with the software, and to consider the other licenses as well?

Thank you so much in advance

*edit

I added a screenshot of what I see
[image: screenshot of the results that I see when I did an xray scan using the xray/newreport functionality and scanned for license violation]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the licenses shown? are you seeing source-jfrog or source-file?

Comment: Hey @kashif. I updated the original post with a screenshot of what I am seeing. Apologies that I am not the most familiar when it comes to jfrog. but anyway, I essentially did an on demand report generation under the xray tab for license violation, and wasn't expecting numpy to show anything else but bsd only license.